# Mi consulta no devuelve nada de la base de datos

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hola estoy haciendo una petición con fetch a un archivo php para que consulte si el usuario tiene o no un certificado pero al parecer después de ejecutar la consulta me muestra un archivo json vacío, que podría estar mal, les agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

codigo php de la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me retorna al utilizar postman o thunder client para enviar peticiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal como ves en el var_dump, lo que te muestra es un objeto mysqli_result, y **no** sus datos. Para sacar sus datos debes hacer un mysqli_fetch de algun tipo sobre el $resultado, y entonces sí puedes hacer un json_encode de ellos.

Comment: se me olvido quitar el var_dump, pero ya añadí otra imagen que muestra la situación sin el var_dump

Comment: que tipo de fetch recomiendas para manejar 1 solo registro?

Comment: da igual lo del var_dump, de hecho confirma mi anterior comentario.  ¿No sabes lo que es un mysqli_fetch?  Entonces es que debes estar comenzando con la programación en PHP de consulta de bases de datos y te recomiendo que busques información sobre ello, por ejemplo, en la documentación oficial, [en este enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php?#example-1489) encontrarás un ejemplo de lo que hacer despues del mysqli_query.

Comment: ok muchas gracias, si soy novato en esto de las consultas